# Average on a sheets Excel Vba

Tags: vba, excel

I have a sheets with 1,800,000 rows and 100 columns. The first column is the time column and each cell in the column correspond to an increment of 0.002 s (more or less) for a total of 3600 sec. I'm trying to make an average of the values in each of the other columns for 1s step ( i sum all the value in 1s step, I divide for the step number and i get the average). Then I clear all the values and I just copy the Value i get for every 1s step. My code works but i guess there is a better way to do that because this is very slow due to the big amount of data.

```
Option Explicit
Sub AverageResult()

'-------dall altro script
Dim LastRowInca As Long
Dim FirstRowInca As Long
Dim LastRow As Long
Dim FirstRow As Long
'-------dall'altro script


Dim i As Long
Dim t1 As Long
Dim t2 As Long
Dim variable As Long
Dim avg As Long
Dim numSampling As Long
numSampling = 0
Dim ColumnSelected As Long



'lunghezza della colonna del tempo
Dim timeColumn As Long
timeColumn = Sheets(1).UsedRange.Rows(Sheets(1).UsedRange.Rows.Count).Row

'numero totale di colonne
Dim totColumn As Long
totColumn = Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
totColumn = Sheets(1).UsedRange.Columns(Sheets(1).UsedRange.Columns.Count).Column

FirstRowInca = 2

For ColumnSelected = 2 To totColumn
t1 = 0
t2 = 1
variable = 0
avg = 0
numSampling = 0

Debug.Print "colonna selezionata"; ColumnSelected
For i = FirstRowInca To timeColumn

Debug.Print "calcolo la riga"; i; "colonna"; ColumnSelected
' definisco l'intervallo di un secondo in cui deve fare la media
If Cells(i, 1).Value > t1 And Cells(i, 1).Value <= t2 Then
    'calcolo la prima variabile se la cella non è vuota
    If Cells(i, ColumnSelected).Value <> "" Then
    variable = variable + Sheets(1).Cells(i, ColumnSelected).Value

    'Setto la cella come vuota
    Cells(i, ColumnSelected).Value = ""

    'Segno il divisore
    numSampling = numSampling + 1

'Se la cella come vuota
    ElseIf Cells(i, ColumnSelected).Value = "" Then
    Debug.Print "Vuoto"
    End If
Else
'Faccio il valore medio e passo all'intervallo successivo
If numSampling <> 0 Then
avg = variable / (numSampling)
'metto nella cella precedente il valore
Cells(i - 1, ColumnSelected).Value = avg
Debug.Print "la media è"; avg; "l'intervallo era"; t1; "a"; t2; "la riga è"; i
variable = 0
avg = 0
numSampling = 0
t1 = t1 + 1
t2 = t2 + 1
If Cells(i, ColumnSelected).Value <> "" Then
    variable = variable + Sheets(1).Cells(i, ColumnSelected).Value
    'Setto la cella come vuota
    Cells(i, ColumnSelected).Value = ""
    'Segno il divisore
    numSampling = numSampling + 1

'Se la cella come vuota
    ElseIf Cells(i, ColumnSelected).Value = "" Then
    Debug.Print "Vuoto"
    End If
    End If
End If

Next i
Next ColumnSelected





End Sub
```

Comment: Excel is not well suited for medium/big data sets like this. I strongly recommend considering alternative tools that are meant for working with large data, such as the programming language R. Python is another good option. Both are completely free and there's tons of good documentation out there on how to use them. They both also have very active communities here on this website.

Comment: "1 800 000 rows" ???

Comment: You'll want to use an Array to process the data instead of directly accessing each cell. Accessing individual cells is much slower.

Comment: @SJR lots of people go through a lot of pain just to avoid having to deal with a database, apparently ;0)

Answer (score 0):

I'd like to suggest a different approach - a one without VBA and just plain Excel formula.
You will have to add two columns next to your data. In this example I have a timestamp in column A and a value in column B. Column C have a formula `=TRUNC(A1)` and column D have this formula `=IF(C1<>C2,AVERAGEIF(C:C,C1,B:B),"")`

[image: Example]

Comment: The OP wanted to also clear out the excess data. To achieve that using this remove duplicate values could be used based on column C. I'm curious how much time this would have with almost 2 million rows however.